# accessing post data on node server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to send simple form data to a node/express server using AJAX. When  submit, I'm brought to a Cannot POST / page and while I'm able to console.log a req, it doesn't include the data from the form. What am I missing?

Form

```
<form method="POST" class="form-group">
    <label for="sentenceCount">Sentences</label>
     <input type="number" placeholder="10" name="sentence count" id="sentenceCount" class="form-control parameters">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Submit</button>

</form>
```

AJAX Request
 $('button').on('click', function(data) {

```
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                url: '/data',
               type: "POST"

            })
        }

    )
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(8000)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/Index.html', {
        root: __dirname
    })
});

app.post('/data', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req)
})
```

Update:

I've fiddled around and have be able to access a body property but the body is empty and cannot get the input values I need.

AJAX:

```
 $('button').on('click', function(data) {
         var formData = $('input').val();
        console.log(formData)

            $.ajax({
                data: formData,
                url: '/data',
               type: "post"

            })
        }

    )
```

Server:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('/Index.html', {
    root: __dirname
})
});

    app.use(bodyParser.json())

    app.post('/data', function(req, res)  {
        console.log(req.body)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot body parser.

1. Install [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) package `npm i body-parser`
2. Add body parser JSON middleware before express routes.

Example:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

And form data should be an object encoded with JSON:

```
 $('button').on('click', function(data) {
     var formData = $('input').val();
        $.ajax({
            data: {value: formData},
            url: '/data',
           type: "post"

        })
    }

)
```

Comment: thanks. 

couple questions: 

Why did you use app.get() the form is a post request? When I use .get nothing is logged but with post it is. 
However, the body is empty on the post. Any idea why the data isn't moving through?

Comment: 1. Fix get/post issue. 2. Form data is not a valid JSON.